# how to get value from db table using distinct mysql query in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table (department_tbl)

```
id     department     user

1       depart1        aa

2       depart1        bb

3       depart3        cc

4       depart2        dd

5       depart4        ee

6       depart4        ff

7       depart2        gg

8       depart1        hh

9       depart5        ii

I want to show all departments and corresponding user below .
like this,

depart1     depart2     depart3    depart4    depart5

aa            dd          cc         ee          ii

bb            gg                     ff

hh
```

iam useing this mysql query

```
$sql=mysql_query( "SELECT DISTINCT departnment FROM department_tbl");
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($sql){
<td><?php echo $r['department'];}?><td>
```

i got  "depart1     depart2     depart3    depart4    depart5"

but not could not get corresponding  user details based on department.

```
while($rr=mysql_fetch_array($sql){?>
<td><?php echo $rr['user'];}?><td>
```

i want output like this,

```
depart1     depart2     depart3    depart4    depart5

aa            dd          cc         ee          ii

bb            gg                     ff

hh
```

Comment: I think you actually want to use a `GROUP BY` rather than a `DISTINCT` maybe `SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(user, ' ') as users FROM department_tbl` (untested off the top of my head)

Comment: so first make sure to also load the user from the db (right now you're only selecting department), then make a temporary array which you fill with the user values, and after having displayed all departments, simply display all those users

Answer (score 0):

```
 $sql=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT departnment as dpt FROM department_tbl");

      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
      {
           $now_dpt =  $row['dpt'];
           $sql1 =  mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM department_tbl where departnment='$now_dpt'");

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
            { 
                $now_id = $row['id'];
                $now_user= $row['user'];
                }
        }
 echo  $now_dpt .'-'.$now_id.'-'.$now_user;
```

Comment: Chris, please don't do a code dump without a little words of wisdom of your own.